# Can I drop arrows down after hitting a mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I shoot an arrow past a fence above me into a skeleton, is there any way to have the arrow land next to me? I want to know for some experiments I'm doing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your arrow hits a skeleton it doesn't return, the entity disappears when you hit the skeleton. If the arrow doesn't hit the skeleton, it will land next to you or directly on you depending on how straight up you shot it. If you mean the skeleton, I don't think it can even detect you through the fence block. If it's in the open, then won't it just climb off the fence block and run towards you? I think the answer in short is no, no matter what you meant, unless you meant you don't hit the skeleton, you're not going to get an arrow to land next to you.